# Heat semigroup in Heisenberg groups properties

Tags: reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators, heisenberg-group

I'm trying to find the construction of the heat semigroup in Heisenberg groups, but I haven't found anything. In particular, I'm trying to find out if the semigroup in the Heisenberg group has the properties of being of class $C_0$ and analytic, to find out if some results from Regularity of Mild Solutions for Analytic Semigroups are valid as

[image]

This result is from PAZY's book and provides regularity for the problem $u_t - Au(t) = f(t)$. Are there similar results for the heat semigroup in Heisenberg groups (or in Lie groups in general)? Can you recommend me some book/article? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is equation (3.1)?

Comment: The Heisenberg sub-Laplacian is self-adjoint on $L^2$ with respect to Haar measure, so you can study the heat semigroup with Hilbert space techniques and spectral theory, which are a lot simpler than the Banach space setting of Pazy's book as I recall it.

Comment: @NateEldredge (3.1) is the equation $u_t -Au(t) = f(t)$, with $u(0)=x$